# react native setstate not changing the state value

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**was working on react native class component

the setState func is not updating the state
I get a output on console as:
hello
byezz

Pls save me!

**

```
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      light : false,
      AC : false
    }
    console.log("hello")

    this.setState({ light: true }, () => { console.log("state changed") })
    console.log("byezz")
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Home Assistant
        </Text>
        <ScrollView>
          <Card />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are setting state in the constructor. setState is to change the default value which you set in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the `this.setState()` call in `componentDidMount` like:

```js
export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      light : false,
      AC : false
    }
    console.log("hello")
    console.log("byezz")
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ light: true }, () => { console.log("state changed") })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Home Assistant
        </Text>
        <ScrollView>
          <Card />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that setting the state in the `constructor` is useless as there you can set the state directly by using the `state` object. Updating the state triggers a re-render, which makes sense only if your component has been rendered once (and hasn't even rendered in the constructor)